# JSON : Syntax error : Unexpectedd token n

Tags: javascript, json

My string is : `"{"name":"caa-shadow-demo1","css":".caa-shadow-demo1 { box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(152,152,152);}","html":"<li><div class=\"caa-shadow-demo1 caa-box-shadow-demo\">DEMO 1</div></li>"}"`. 
 It shows unexpected token n.

Comment: Are you using var x = JSON.parse(); ?

Comment: no, simply JSON.parse(string)

Comment: Error persist in both cases.

Comment: When I assign your string as a variable, it works fine: var x = {"name":"caa-shadow-demo1","css":".caa-shadow-demo1 { box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(152,152,152);}","html":"<li><div class=\"caa-shadow-demo1 caa-box-shadow-demo\">DEMO 1</div></li>"}; x.name;

Comment: Because it's already an object you do not need to parse it.

Comment: You need to double escape it. Try `JSON.parse('{"name":"caa-shadow-demo1","css":".caa-shadow-demo1 { box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(152,152,152);}","html":"<li><div class=\\"caa-shadow-demo1 caa-box-shadow-demo\\">DEMO 1</div></li>"}')`

Comment: @PeterButcher OP says it's a string, they probably just forgot the quotation marks.

Comment: Yup var X= string is working. I got this string after JSON.stringify so i thought i have to parse it to make it obj back again. Thanks.

Comment: But why  double esc?

Comment: @DJDavid98 Yes, that wasn't clear initially.

Comment: Because the JSON parser expects double quotes to be escaped, which means you need to escape the slashes in JS to preserve the escapes in the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Assign your object to a variable like this:

```
var x = {"name":"caa-shadow-demo1","css":".caa-shadow-demo1 { box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(152,152,152);}","html":"<li><div class=\"caa-shadow-demo1 caa-box-shadow-demo\">DEMO 1</div></li>"}
```

Then simply use:

```
x.name
```

And:

```
x.css
```

To access the object values.

Since it's already an object there is no need to use `JSON.parse()`

If your object is in string form then you will need to parse it.